# Loop through a list, compare value to a threshold and copy and paste a corresponding value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet data with a list of companies and percentages corresponding to those companies. On worksheet Dashboard I have a threshold (say 20%)

I want to look through the percentages for each company and if the percentage is lower than the threshold (20%) then I want to copy that company into the next available row in column B on worksheet Dashboard.

The code I have so far is:

```
Sub companydraw()

Set wsDest = Sheets("Dashboard")
Set wsData = Sheets("Data")


wsDest.Columns("B").Rows(7 & ":" & wsDest.Rows.Count).ClearContents

lr = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = wsData.Range("W5: W418")

For Each i In rRng

If i.Value > wsDest.Range("F2").Value Then

    wsData.Range("N5:N" & lr).Copy wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

My code posts all companies on one iteration, which is not correct as it is not taking into account all percentages of a all companies, it was then prompts me to save the spreadsheet which I don't understand.

if anyone can help it would be amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your script you wish to check the value in column W from the data sheet against the value in F2 in the destination sheet and then copy the value from column N in the datasheet in the corresponding row to column B in the destination sheet in the next available row.

This should do it:

```
Sub companydraw()
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim writerow As Integer

Set wsDest = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")

writerow = wsDest.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastrow = wsData.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If wsData.Range("W" & i).value < wsDest.Range("F2").value Then 'F2 holds the threshold value
        wsDest.Range("B" & writerow).value = wsData.Range("N" & i).value
        writerow = writerow + 1
    End If
Next i

Set wsData = Nothing
Set wsDest = Nothing
End Sub
```